# Concatenate tuple elements as string where one element is string and the other is a tuple of integers

Tags: python, random, passwords

the prompt is:

Write a Python program that prompts the user to enter his or her name and then creates a secret password consisting of three letters (in lowercase) randomly picked up from his or her name, and a random four-digit number. For example, if the user enters “Vassilis Bouras” a secret password can probably be one of “sar1359” or “vbs7281” or “bor1459”. Space characters are not allowed in the secret password. You will have to use string slicing, random, lower, and446670 concatenation.

my code is:

```
import random

name = input("Enter your name all lowercase ")

name2 = name.replace(" ", "")

letter1 = random.choice(name2)
letter2 = random.choice(name2)
letter3 = random.choice(name2)
letter4 = random.choice(name2)

passwordnumber = (random.randint(0, 9),
                  random.randint(0, 9),
                  random.randint(0, 9),
                  random.randint(0, 9))

passwordletter = (letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4)

password = passwordletter, passwordnumber

print(password)
```

Now I entered the name "nick g" into the program and got:

('nigc', (5, 4, 9, 6))

What I'm wondering is how can I make the output put the letters numbers together without spacing them out like this and putting parenthesis. any help is very appreciated thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please consider formatting the code elements in your post properly (indent 4 spaces or use backticks for inline blocks).  Also, if you could provide the exact expected output (which I believe is `nigc5496`), and a consistent random seed (so that everyone can check against the same answer), that'd make your post even better.

Comment: The instructions say "consisting of three letters", but your example uses _four_ letters. That's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the numbers to strings, put them together as one string with `join`, and then concatenate with the letters:

```
password = ('nigc', (5, 4, 9, 6))

password[0] + ''.join([str(x) for x in password[1]])
# 'nigc5496'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code and use a [string format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to format your passwords. For instance:

```
import random

name = "Guido van Rossum"

name2 = name.replace(" ", "")

letter1 = random.choice(name2)
letter2 = random.choice(name2)
letter3 = random.choice(name2)
letter4 = random.choice(name2)

num1 = random.randint(0, 9)
num2 = random.randint(0, 9)
num3 = random.randint(0, 9)
num4 = random.randint(0, 9)

print(f"{letter1}{letter2}{letter3}{letter4}{num1}{num2}{num3}{num4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *formatted* printing and unpack the `passwordnumber` *tuple*

```
print('{}{}{}{}{}'.format(passwordletter, *passwordnumber)
# nigc5496
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all going in the right direction, just some confusion around strings and tuples to clear up. The reason you have brackets in the answer is that

```
(random.randint(0, 9),
 random.randint(0, 9),
 random.randint(0, 9),
 random.randint(0, 9))
```

(numbers separate by commas, in round brackets) and

```
passwordletter, passwordnumber
```

are tuples. You have ended up with a 4-tuple (the digits) inside a 2-tuple. Python is bracketing them to let you know:

```
('nigc', (5, 4, 9, 6))
```

means a 2-tuple with a string in the first place, and an embedded 4-tuple in the second place.

What needs to happen now is:

1. joining the 4-tuple together to make a string
2. add the strings to each other to get the full password

Before joining the numbers into a string, you need to convert the numbers themselves into strings, otherwise you'll get a `TypeError` when you try to add integers to strings. `str(5)` produces the string `'5'` so let's use `str()` on each of your numbers:

```
passwordnumber = (str(random.randint(0, 9)),
                  str(random.randint(0, 9)),
                  str(random.randint(0, 9)),
                  str(random.randint(0, 9)))
```

But this is getting repetitive and complicated to read. And what if security got tighter and you wanted a 12-digit password? Python has a useful facility called a list comprehension, which is great for building lists of any size. We can use one to build a list of numbers without repeating code:

```
numbers_list = [str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(4)]
```

Here's a full answer, much shorter than yours, using comprehensions and a few other useful bits of Python. Note the use of`str()` to convert numbers to strings before joining, as mentioned above.

```
from random import choice, randint

name = 'Sherlock Holmes'
name_as_word_list = name.lower().split()
name_no_spaces = ''.join(name_as_word_list)

letters_list = [choice(name_no_spaces) for _ in range(3)]
numbers_list = [str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(4)]
password = ''.join(letters_list + numbers_list)
print(password)
```